# environment variables cause make's undefine to fail (Windows)

Tags: windows, variables, makefile, environment

In Windows, I'm getting a failure in make (GnuWin32) when I try to undefine a variable that was defined in my environment:

```
C:\>make
makefile:2: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

My environment has LIB defined, probably from another installed program. (Right Click 'Computer' -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables...).

The only contents of makefile:

```
ifdef LIB
undefine LIB
endif
```

How do I undefine LIB? I'm using -rR options, but it doesn't seem like there's one to avoid bringing in environment variables (i.e. LIB).

Answer (score 2):

You should always provide version information for the tools you're using.

In this case I'd say you're using an older version of GNU make; the `undefine` feature was added in GNU make 3.82 so if your version is older than that, you won't be able to use it.